# SLI with MOBILE nVidia cards and latest proprietary driver?

Tags: nvidia, laptop, lenovo, 17.04

I read and searched quite a while, but SLI information is sort of confusing...

I am trying to get my **Lenovo Y500**, 2x **650M** nVidias, to run in **SLI** with **Ubuntu 17.04** and latest **381.09 driver** from nVidia.

No freaking way to get SLI going. Apart from that both cards are recognized, I can use the second for CUDA stuff etc, - but I can't get them to power the same display.

Is nVidia serious about *NOT supporting mobile GPUs* in their Linux drivers, as someone mentioned in a forum post?

Anyone here been able to get SLI working on a dual-GPU laptop with some workaround?

thanks for any and all hints...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and two 650M cards which are working in SLI on Windows, but for Ubuntu it is not possible. I've done some research in that case and come with information that mobile cards are not SLI-capable on Linux systems. This info as I remember comes from original nVidia site. Also when looking on GeForce page, the 650M is not listed as a SLI card: [link](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/supported-gpus). Strange, as it is working in SLI mode on Windows.